# Custom init.d script issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to setup a new service with in `init.d` folder, but I am having a strange issue this time. I created a new service and just put a echo there:

`echo "asdsad"`

When I call it without parameters, looks perfect:

`brunomanzo@platform-hdfs-01:/etc$ sudo service hadoop-hdfs 
asdsad:`

But when I call with a start/stop param, it prints nothing:

`brunomanzo@platform-hdfs-01:/etc$ sudo service hadoop-hdfs start`

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su], [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com) or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The file must be in /etc/init.d/

2) You are missing this

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs
sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs
```

My result after testing

```
root@server:/# echo "echo \"Test service\"">> /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs
root@server:/# chmod 755 /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs
root@server:/# chown root:root /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs
root@server:/# sudo service hadoop-hdfs
Test service
root@server:/# sudo service hadoop-hdfs start
Test services
root@server:/# service hadoop-hdfs start
Test services
```

Tested

```
1) with sudo
2) without sudo
3) with start
4) without start
```